# Intellij plugin JBTabbedPane UI replaced after theme switch

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I added a toolwindow by a plugin with JBTabbedPane in it.

When a user switches the theme from Intellij to Darcula and back (or vice-versa), IDE gets side UI instead of my class.

I use Intellij 2019.1.3 but the same behavior in 2018.3 and some other

STR:
1. Run Gradle task runIDE
2. open project
3. change the theme to Darcula and apply
4. change the theme to Intellij and apply

https://github.com/yrakovets/tabbedPaneTest.git

Expected: JBTabbedPane UI will be similar after 2nd step and after 4th step

Actual : different UI

Answer (score 0):

I made the fix for my problem. It doesn't work correctly in the sample, but in my project it does. I "return" the UI back in PropertyChangeListener)

```
pane.addPropertyChangeListener(evt -> {
            if (!pane.getUI().equals(ui)) {
                pane.setUI(ui);
            }
        });
```